# ETF currency confusion: EUR vs GBP

Tags: etf, currency

Currency confusion.

Looking at the ETF: [Stoxx Europe 600 UCITS ETF 1C](https://etf.dws.com/en-gb/LU0328475792-stoxx-europe-600-ucits-etf-1c-/), it says: "Share Class Currency: EUR".

Listed on the London Stock Exchange, this fund has the price listed in GBP.

I need to have GBP to buy it?

Is this EUR or GBP fund?

Am I protected against EUR/GBP swings in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to have GBP to buy it?

Yes, because it is listed in the LSE - if this is a problem, it should be easy to find other versions of this same product in other exchanges, where it is denominated in a different currency.

> Is this EUR or GBP fund?

According to the KII, its shares are in EUR.

> Am I protected against EUR/GBP swings in this case?

Absolutely not - for example, the fund could give excellent results in say, this year, but the GBP could strengthen even more VS the EUR over the same period. In that (hypothetical) situation, you could end up with a loss.

Comment: Than what does it mean "Share Class Currency: EUR"?? Isn't it a bit missleading? I never want to depend on EUR/GBP swings.

Comment: @Danijel: It means that the ETF does its accounting in Euro.